# Why do some of my nectarines have missing skin and deeply damaged interior sections?

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, nectarines

I have an approximately 4 ft tall baby nectarine tree. Some, but not all, of the fruits, have large areas of missing skin, and deeply damaged dark interior sections.

I live in zone 9b in Northern California.

What could be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Coryneum blight is also called shot hole disease - This is a fungus issue - Spray with a2-5% Chitosan solution as a tree drench - remove fruit that have dropped or developing fungus.

Answer (score 0):

[Western Flower Thrip](http://www.omafra.gov.on.ca/IPM/english/tender/insects/thrips.html)

This is a guess until we have more information, ID of the thrip for example? Do you have any blooms left?  This article tells you how to find the insects (they are tiny).  A little specimen microscope and or a camera with micro capabilities.

Comment: That's sounds scary to control, only a couple of them are affected, hope it was affected when the tree was in nursery and didn't bring that trouble home

Comment: No blooms left,. Will have to wait for next year?

Comment: Hold up!!  Are you saying this tree is in a pot, the same pot you purchased it in at the nursery?  How long have you had this tree?  I would grab a few of those fruits and head to that nursery.  You better believe this could be from the nursery.  They should know about this for sure.  They might have other customers with thrip infected trees.  While at the nursery, first thing go look at the other trees that were with yours.  They might have pulled all the suspicious fruit.  Look at the ground.  You could then be armed with proof. They should get you a new fresh tree.

Comment: Bought it about 3 months back.. but just realized it's from Costco not my usual nursery.. guess I'll wait for next year or other good looking fruits to rippen and keep posted what I ended up doing. Thank you stormy for all your time, appreciate your invaluable guidance

Comment: Costco?  What is the difference?  I'll bet this tree had thrips before you purchased it...Costco  is even more caring about customer satisfaction, they can afford to make customers happy.  They expect to make customers unhappy. Too much merchandise, too many people.  They also expect unhappy customers to not rock the boat.  They are just as vulnerable as your nursery, more vulnerable because plants aren't their forte.  Clean up debris like a mad man.  3 months is not that long of a time. I would definitely take your nectarine ruined fruit and be the squeaky nail at Costco.  A positive thing...

Comment: Is there any updates, since it's a year later?